# `bookdown`/`rmarkdown`/`knitr`: Child documents and path definition in `YAML` headers

Tags: r, yaml, knitr, r-markdown, bookdown

I'm building a reporting infrastructure that makes extensive use of child documents (via `{r, child = 'somedir/child_doc.Rmd'}`) AND is parametrized through the `params` dictionary in the `YAML` header of the master document. An example might be:

```
---
title: Project Report
subtitle: POIGNANT DESCRIPTION OF THE WORK AT HAND
date: '`r format(Sys.time(), "%d %B, %Y")`'
output:
  bookdown::pdf_document2:
    template: ~
    toc: yes
    toc_depth: 2
colorlinks: yes
fontsize: 11pt
documentclass: scrartcl
geometry: margin=1in, a4paper
params:
  submodule:
    value:
      intro:
        data_dir: 'data'
---
```

Using this structure, accessing `data_dir` becomes problematic as the working directory differs for the master and child documents and thus relative path definitions also diverge. Ways out are:

1. Usage of absolute/expanded path names in defining `data_dir`. **Gets long/unwieldy quickly.**
2. Postprocessing of the `params` object to expand the path within the master document. As `params` is immutable when accessed from within `R` chunks, this can only be solved in an **inelegant** manner:

   ````
   ```{r params-processing, include = FALSE}
   local_params <- params
   local_params$submodule$intro$data_dir <- path.expand(local_params$submodule$intro$data_dir)
   ````

   Followed by internal usage of `local_params` instead of `params`.
3. In-place expansion of the path using something like `!R path.expand('data')` when defining the parameter in the `YAML` header. While this (or the `-based equivalent) works for the `data` field in the example, `knitr`ing **fails** in the path case as the `R` expression is *not* expanded but used as a character-representation - and literal `"path.expand('data')"` obviously doesn't exist as a path.

I'd appreciate any hints on how to solve this prettily - especially whether 3. can be made work ...

Answer (score 7):

The [source code of `r-yaml`](https://github.com/viking/r-yaml/blob/97612f95086b9b65d38b6a732f72c45dc3b7c1cc/src/r_parse.c#L351) (which is implicitly called by `bookdown::render_book`) shows you can solve option 3 fairly easily by parsing the relative path with the `expr` tag:

```
params:
  submodule:
    value:
      intro:
        data_dir: !expr normalizePath('data')
```

This evaluates the R expression in the YAML and doesn't require any further processing.

`data_dir: !r normalizePath('data')` is also acceptable syntax which is processed by [`knitr`](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/blob/f76458d3c71c833f07f2d9f03cca06abd965e2fe/R/params.R#L61). Unfortunately just neither of `!R` or `` `r ``, the two you tried, are interpreted.

---

I also suggest using `normalizePath` instead as it returns an absolute path given any relative directory. Your example of using `path.expand` only performs tilde expansion so has no effect on a local relative path such as `'data'`. `normalizePath` actually calls `path.expand` as a first step.

Simply access the fully expanded path as usual

````
```{r params-processing}
print(params$submodule$intro$data_dir)
```
## $value
## [1] "/Users/user_name/full_path_to_book/my_book/data"
##
## $expr
## [1] "normalizePath('data')"
##
## attr(,"class")
## [1] "knit_param_expr"
````

Note, it might be best to use `!r` seeing as the `r-yaml` behaviour may change as it currently throws a warning:

```
Warning message:
In yaml.load(readLines(con), error.label = error.label, ...) :
  R expressions in yaml.load will not be auto-evaluated by default in the near future
```