# Parameterize path for `reference_docx` in a Rmarkdown document with `rmarkdown::word_document` output format

Tags: r, yaml, r-markdown, knitr

I am trying to use a parameterized path for a `reference_docx` in a Rmarkdown document with `rmarkdown::word_document` output format, in a similar way as e.g. is done [here](https://richardjacton.github.io/Advanced-Rmarkdown-YAML-headers/) for the bibliography file (section **Bibliograghy and Citation YAML options**).

However, it seems like this feature does not work for the `reference_docx` option, as expressions passed to the arguments of the output format function (`rmarkdown::word_document`, or `bookdown::word_document2` for that matter) are interpreted literally instead of evaluated. See e.g. this minimal reprex:

- Working example:

```
---
params:
  ref: www/Template_doc.docx
output:
  word_document:
    reference_docx: www/Template_doc.docx
---

Some markdown stuff
```

- Equivalent non-working example:

```yaml
---
params:
  ref: www/Template_doc.docx
output:
  word_document:
    reference_docx: "`r params$ref`"
---

Some markdown stuff
```

This example gives the following error when trying to knit:

`` pandoc.exe: `r params$ref`: openBinaryFile: does not exist (No such file or directory) ``

That is, it tries to use `` `r params$ref` `` exactly as the file name, instead of evaluating `params$ref`

I have also tried with (as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48358541/1585338)):

- `!r params$ref`: it apparently ignores the `!r` altogether and considers `params$ref` to be the intended file name
- `!expr params$ref`: it gives the following error:

```txt
Error: object 'params' not found
Error in yaml::yaml.load(..., eval.expr = TRUE) : 
  Could not evaluate expression: params$ref
Calls: <Anonymous> ... parse_yaml_front_matter -> yaml_load -> <Anonymous>
Execution halted
```

Any ideas on how to solve this? Many thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, the problem is with trying to access `params` from within the `yaml` header itself. As stated [here](https://github.com/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/issues/277),

> Finally, `params` (the list of parameters provided within the knitting environment) is not available for yaml expressions.

Other than that, the field `reference_docx` can evaluate expressions the same way as other `yaml` header fields, [see e.g.](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/1387).

Consequently, my own (working) example, adapted to this, would be:

```yaml
---
params:
  ref: www/Template_doc.docx
output:
  word_document:
    reference_docx: !expr file.path("www", "Template_doc.docx")
---

Some markdown stuff
```